Growpart and resize2fs not automatically running on boot of Ubuntu Server 24.04 (amd64). How to fix?
I am running Ubuntu Server 24.04 on a PC. Every so often I like to remove the drive it is installed on, and use ApplePi-Baker on my mac to shrink the root partition and then back up the entire drive to a bootable .iso file. Then, to restore, I just flash the .iso file (with the shrunken root partition) to a drive or usb stick, then plug it back into my PC and boot up the restored drive. On Ubuntu 20.04, when I do this, the root partition automatically expands itself on boot using growpart and resize2fs. However, in Ubuntu 24.04, the root filesystem and partition is NOT expanded on boot. So something is broken in Ubuntu 24.04 that prevents growpart and resize2fs from detecting the shrunken partition and expanding it on boot.
Can someone help me detect what is wrong and how to fix it so that my root partitions expand on boot on Ubuntu 24.04? Thanks.
